# CMake Error "required internal CMake variable not set" for CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT and CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY

Tags: c++, cmake

I am following this [tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20a%20Library.html) about how to use `cmake` to link a library in a single different directory, but getting these errors whetn `cmake ..` inside `build/` directory

```
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY
```

The project is as this

```
/build
/CMakeLists.txt
/tutorial.cpp
/math
  /CMakeLists.txt
  /half.h
  /half.cpp
```

```
# /CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

add_subdirectory(math)
project(Tutorial)
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Tutorial PUBLIC math)
target_include_directories(
  Tutorial PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/math")
```

```
// /tutorial.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <half.h>

int main() {

  std::cout << half(5) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

```
# /math/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(math half.cpp)
```

```
// /math/half.h

#ifndef MATH_H
#define MATH_H

float half(int v);

#endif /*MATH_H*/
```

```
// /math/half.cpp

#include <half.h>

float half(int v) {
  return v/2;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should either call `project` in the main `CMakeLists.txt` **before** `add_subdirectory(math)` or call `project` in the `math/CMakeLists.txt` (before `add_library`).

Comment: That worked out